# Fixing "You don't have permission to access /qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi on this server"

Tags: installation, windows, qgis-server

I installed QGIS server ltr 64 bit version from osGeo4W, then I installed Apache 64 bit httpd-2.4.29-Win64-VC15, along with mod_fcgid-2.3.9-win64-VC15, I followed the instructions on [Adding QGIS Server to an existing Windows web server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86348/adding-qgis-server-to-an-existing-windows-web-server) exactly, 
still I am getting error: You don't have permission to access /qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi on this server

PS: the Apache server is running, I changed the corresponding changes in Conf files. I am trying to run all of this on one machine which has windows 10 on it.

Comment: For future reference: same (unanswered) question by a different user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667999/apache-error-403-forbidden-qgis

Comment: which user is running the apache service?

Comment: The Apache24 is being run as administrator using my account, is that what you are asking.